# How to get MPMoviePlayerController frame size right in UITableViewCell on first display?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UITableView with a number of custom UITableViewCells. One of those custom cell types displays short videos.

My problem is that I can't get the MPMoviePlayerController frame size to line up with its container view when each cell initially displays. It's too wide and not tall enough, as in this screengrab (the space it should fill is the light grey area):

[image: MPMoviePlayerController frame on initial UITableViewCell display]

However, when I scroll the UITableView so the cell disappears out of view, then scroll so it comes back into view, the MPMoviePlayerController frame has resized correctly, as in this screengrab (albeit with the black background from its original frame):

[image: MPMoviePlayerController frame when UITableViewCell has been scrolled out of and back into view]

Here's how I'm setting up the video inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videourl)
moviePlayer.view.frame = cell.cellVideo.bounds
cell.cellVideo.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
moviePlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded
moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFit
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = false
moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
return cell
```

So, can anyone shed some light on why this is happening - and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What I ended up doing was using AVPlayer instead and grabbing a thumbnail from the first second of the video which I then displayed within the table cells as an image.